# Does ant design have a similar breakpoint check analagous to material-ui?

Tags: antd

Material UI has a handy function of checking for breakpoints for example.

```
const matchesSM = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
```

So if the screen size goes below sm then `matchesSM` becomes true.

Does Ant Design have a similar feature?

Comment: I just saw in the docs that there are 3rd party libraries available.  react-responsive and react-media.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's called `useBreakpoint`.
Here's the doc: https://ant.design/components/grid/#components-grid-demo-useBreakpoint

Comment: Can you use the useBreakpoint hook directly from the import without importing Grid like so? ```import useBreakpoint from 'antd/lib/grid/hooks/useBreakpoint';```